# Cliente de SNMP desde Windows

Tags: windows

Resulta que necesito utilizar un cliente de SNMP en Windows para comunicarme con un switch y darle al mismo una orden sencilla: como que suspenda un puerto para quitar la conexión de red de un nodo concreto.

El pc desde el que quiero instalar el cliente de SNMP es un nodo de la misma red, pero con privilegios.

Esta es la solución que se me ha ocurrido para mi problema:

-Tener la potestad de no permitir la conexión de red a un determinado equipo de mi red desde otro nodo. Pero no tengo muy claro como funcionaría dicho cliente de SNMP en Windows. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Te sugiero que lleves a cabo tu idea. Y si al desarrollarla te enfrentas con __un problema real de programación__, en Stackoverflow en español siempre hay usuarios dispuestos a compartir su tiempo en ayudarte. Te invito a que conozcas más sobre esta comunidad [haciendo el recorrido de presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).